# How to run a python and unity3d script concurrently?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, sockets

I currently have a python script which takes in information from a webcam and does some processing to output a set of coordinates which is constantly being updated live. I want to send these coordinates to unity3d and have seen that I can do this through sockets.

However I was wondering how would I run the python script live and have the changes seen in unity live in real time? Is there a way to run the python script from unity it self?

Comment: Have you checked out things like [Python for Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@7.0/manual/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

What I did years ago for a similar problem, was to send a request from unity through a socket, and have the python server receive the request, compute the necessary stuffs, then return the result

Comment: which is basically what OP mentions yes ... ^^